# Mantle.gg EPERM message

Tags: operation, mantle

Im trying to install Mantle.gg to get a free minecraft cape and it keeps saying, when I press load mantle,(at this point im done installing mantle) and I keep getting a EPERM:operation not permitted. I think it might be that Mantle is a virus but I also think that it could be a fixable issue.

All I tried is pressing load mantle and then trying to delete it since I thought it was a virus. Since I couldent delete it (I have restrictions where I need my dads gmail password to install or delete or do some other stuff on my computer) and I was expecting to just get the EPERM messag when I pressed load mantle.